# Amiga A1050 schematic

Tags: amiga, ram, amiga-1000

I’m trying to resurrect a Craigslist Amiga A1000. After replacing Paula it now boots. Several basics still missing (RF shields, screws, port covers, etc.) but essential electronics are okay.

However, I would like to add the 256 KB RAM expansion but I haven't been able to locate one. I have been able to recreate much of the schematic for much of the A1050 (thanks to Raffzahn for excellent information), but not sure of 2 things - 1) capacitors, and 2) the black blob:

1. My guess is 8 the capacitors are 220 nF but don't know about the other one (c9?).  I think they are connected between 5 V and GND?
2. The blob maybe a 39 Ω resistor pack to buffer the address lines? Or?

Any insights/thoughts/facts appreciated.

Front of board:
[image: Front of board]

Back of board:
[image: Back of board]
<sub>Source: http://amiga.resource.cx/exp/a1050</sub>

Comment: Have you measured it?

Comment: The capacitors are probably decoupling capacitors, right? So do you really need to replace them like for like?

Comment: Can you post the schematics that you've created?

Comment: Based on the photos I've seen I'd concur with your take on things.  The caps all appear the same and wired the same (VCC to GND).  One photo I saw had the label `224` on one of them, i.e. 220nF.  The "black blob" is probably 8×39Ω 5% resistors wired straight across (pin 1-16, 2-15, 3-14, 4-13, 5-12, 6-11, 7-10, 8-9).

Comment: @OmarL I think TOD is trying to recreate the board without having physical access to an original board.

Comment: Curious if you have managed to source that edge connector?

Comment: @BrianH Perhaps [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/EDAC/337-060-540-202?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduggCrVwZGW1iZ%2FLhDhdrMP2NHpqJM%252BSrKYRZYHC02Fv3Q%3D%3D) might suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  And the link to the edge connector. I'd just started looking and that one looks promising.  

Yes, trying to recreate one from images and descriptions.  Will share the schematics and board info once I get them clean.  And let you all know if it works.  Also plan to work an option to use easier to find RAM chips.

Comment: Check the datasheet for that connector before purchasing and make sure it's the correct size.  I was measuring off of the image I posted, not physical hardware. Correct pin spacing and the board thickness that it'll accept are the most crucial dimensions to check.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

I think I have all the connections figured out.  Not a complex thing really, but would hate to fry a vintage Amiga. I would like to make the first one mostly match the original A1050 design. If that works, I will make an additional one(s) using newer and fewer components. I suspect learning the CAD and PCB software will be a bigger challenge.  Been decades since I used schematic capture software so I'm starting out as a complete noob. Be glad to share everything. Thanks again. TOD

Answer (score 14):

Finally designed and built an Amiga A1050 knockoff.  Seems to work well on my Amiga 1000.

Schematic, PCB and BOM is posted on github
https://github.com/TheOrangeStrain/Amiga-A1050-RAM-Expansion

The answers to my question are:

- The black blob is indeed a 39 ohm resistor pack
- C1-C8 are 0.22 uf capacitors
- C9 is a 10 uf capacitor

Thank you to those who gave me feedback and input here. It is truly appreciated.

Enjoy,
TOD

Comment: The linked project is excellent and I'm sure anyone wanting to know this will end up going there.  It's the norm here for answers to be able to stand alone, so I took the liberty of editing in the answers to the question.